# Xcode 6 universal app not centered on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I'm working on a uikit app on Xcode 6. I created the project as a universal app, and when I'm putting labels/ui-'stuff' on the storyboard, I'm using the blue guides.

I have the use auto layout and use size classes both checked. When I'm building my app and running in iphone6/5 simulators, the labels that I have centered are not showing up centered.

also, I have wAny and hAny in the storyboard on the bottom

is there some option I'm missing?

Comment: do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "blue guides" have nothing to do with anything. The problem is that you have auto layout *checked* but you are not *using* it. You must make *constraints* to position your interface objects relative to the size of the superview, which will grow or shrink depending on the size of the screen. If you want something to end up centered, use a centering *constraint*. It doesn't matter at all how it looks in Xcode; only the constraints matter.

Comment: I see, I thought the blue lines did something : )  I'll work on these constraints then